# Django how to find if the object is referenced by ForeignKey from another class in model.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two classes shown below, I wanted to add a function to File to check if the file is referenced by any data inside the Project class (similar how "was published recently" is done here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_images/admin12t.png ).

```
class File(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

class Project(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File)
```

Comment: Your models have no link to each other. Didn't you forget to mention that file has a link to project or vice-versa?

Comment: Do you mean to check if any objects of Project has has file ? Also why is project referencing to Project model itself ?

Comment: @Marco Im fresh to Django, could you explain more?

Comment: @Ahtisham I have a other names in my real code, i just changed it for question purposes.
The goal is to add a simple true false if the file is a "lost file" without metadata which is held in other model

Comment: Sorry i just realised i messed up, its fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def is_used_in_a_project(self):
        return self.project_set.exists()
```

Django automatically exposes a `<model>_set` attribute on the other side of a ManyToManyField relation. This is a queryset containing all of the instances that are linked to it via the m2m relation on the other model.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

You can alter the name of this "reverse relation" attribute by setting the `related_name` of the ManyToManyField.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments

e.g. you could define:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    files = models.ManyToManyField(File, related_name="linked_projects")

class File(models.Model):
    def is_used_in_a_project(self):
        return self.linked_projects.exists()
```

Comment: Thank you <3 this is exactly what i was looking for :)